# Как лучше вложить в один оператор if?

Tags: операторы, php

Как лучше вложить в один оператор if. И вообще как лучше проверять откуда пришел запрос с формы?

```
if ($refer != "http://yandex.ru/") {
echo "не передался реф";
exit();
}
if ($refer != "http://www.yandex.ru/") {
echo "не передался реф";
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($refer != "http://yandex.ru/" or $refer != "http://www.yandex.ru/"){
    die;
}
```

Или:

```
$except = array('http://yandex.ru/', 'http://www.yandex.ru/'); //и тд
if(in_array($refer, $except)){
    die;
}
```

Comment: @Costa - во втором случае у вас не будет работать, так как в массив вы поместили строки, но индекс у массива целочисленный, а вы обращаетесь строковым (`$except[$refer]`).

Comment: а если так тоже правильно? if ($refer1 & $refer2 != $refer) {

Comment: if ($refer1 && $refer2 != $refer) {

Comment: ua6xh, спасибо, действительно!

$except = array('http://yandex.ru/', 'http://www.yandex.ru/'); //и тд
if(in_array($refer, $except)){
    die;
}